# Snap point to a specific line

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, snapping

I have been snapping points to lines using distance. In a couple of cases a point has gone to the wrong line, where there is more than two lines near each other. (see photo). How do I move the point to match with the correct line? In this case the line in the bottom of the attached picture.

[image]

Comment: Do you need to have all lines showing when you perform the action? If you write a definition query which filters out the lines you don't want the point to snap to it won't snap to them.

Comment: Maybe I totally misunderstood the question but... if you want to move the point, why can't you open edit session and just move the point to make it match (by using snapping) ?

Comment: @G.Spanish yup. I just moved it. I always think GIS makes it harder than it should be so never consider it lets you do the easy way. Thanks for responses.

Answer (score 2):

To move the point, you can just open an edit session and move the point to make it match (by using snapping).